# Why can't I auto-wire AuthorizationServerTokenServices or ConsumerTokenServices? "There is more than one bean of [this] type"

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm using Spring Boot with OAuth2 and I'm trying to revoke a token. But when i try to auto wire those classes, it tells me they're already in `ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration.class`. I don't have it anywhere in my code (which at this point is very simple).

*NOTE:* I get this error in **any** class I try this in (a component, controller, SpringBootApplication, etc).

How do I get Spring to allow me to inject these?

IDE (IntelliJ) Error:

> Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of '' type.
>
> Beans:  jwkTokenServices (ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration.class)
>          jwkTokenServices (ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration.class)

Spring runtime error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AuthorizationServerTokenServices' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at com.simple.SimpleApplication.main(SimpleApplication.java:40) [classes/:na]

Field authorizationServerTokenServices in com.simple.SimpleApplication required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AuthorizationServerTokenServices' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'jwkTokenServices' not loaded because OAuth JWK Condition did not find key jwk set URI not provided
    - Bean method 'jwtTokenServices' not loaded because OAuth JWT Condition did not find provided public key
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>simple</name>
    <description>SSO project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The class where I get the error:

```
package com.simple;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.FrameworkEndpoint;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AuthorizationServerTokenServices;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.ConsumerTokenServices;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@FrameworkEndpoint
public class RevokeTokenEndpoint {

    @Autowired
    private AuthorizationServerTokenServices authorizationServerTokenServices;

    @Autowired
    private ConsumerTokenServices consumerTokenServices;


}
```

application.yml

```
security:
oauth2:
    client:
    clientId: myclientid
    clientSecret: myclientsecret
    accessTokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
    userAuthorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
    tokenName: oauth_token
    authenticationScheme: query
    clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    sso:
    login-path: /login
    resource:
    userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/me

logging:
level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
    org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like there are several beans of such type. So you need to specify the name of the bean in order to make Autowire work

```
@Autowire
private AuthorizationServerTokenServices defaultAuthorizationServerTokenServices;
```

works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is a bit confusing but it is basically saying that you are missing a bit of configuration.

Look at the source for ResourceServerTokenServices.JwkCondition

You will need to add an entry in your properties for security.oauth2.resource.jwk.key-set-uri.

This is the uri to retrieve the json web key to encrypt the token.

The second error message is for ResourceServerTokenServices.JwtCondition.
It requires either security.oauth2.resource.jwt.key-uri or security.oauth2.resource.jwt.key-value to be set.

Only one of the properties (jwt or jwk) should be configured.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security-oauth2-resource-server.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is default configuration which is provided by Spring, if I got you question right

Comment: OK, so then how do I use those classes to revoke a token? I tried auto-wiring the class that already has them and it doesn't expose it.